# How to toggle class to body tag in Vuejs?

Tags: javascript, data-binding, vue.js

How I can toggle class for body tag, I have tried couple of ways to resolve my problem, but still recieve error message and have no ideas for it. 
So, this is my story:

1. On body tag, I added v-bind:class

```html
<body id="app" v-bind:class='{active:showModal}'>
```

And then I recieved these errors:

```
[Vue warn]: v-bind:class="{active:showModal}": attribute interpolation is not allowed in Vue.js directives and special attributes.
[Vue warn]: Invalid expression. Generated function body:  scope.active:scope.showModal
[Vue warn]: Error when evaluating expression "active:showModal". Turn on debug mode to see stack trace.
```

2. Then I tried to resolve my problem with these changes on body tag:

```html
<body id="app" @v-bind:class='active:showModal'>
```

But I still have one error:

```
[Vue warn]: Invalid expression. Generated function body:  scope.active:scope.showModal
```

How I can resolve that one?

Comment: I cannot reporduce this problem. I made a fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/Linusborg/d791v4q8/

(inspect the element, you will see the class changes just fine. I also tested with the body tag, which works as well - as expected)

Can you provide a reproduction of your problem?

Comment: I have also tried option like this, and it`s just works fine for me. But the differnce is that, this error problem causes in larger app.  I have sample demo, wich i made and included on my site. http://codepen.io/reinis/pen/grLVMG I nested this template immediatly after body tag, modal and data works fine, but that issue cause headaches. Have some any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Vue is trying to evaluate the value of `active` because it isn't quoted.  Just add quotes:

```
<body id="app" :class='{"active":showModal}'>
```

Comment: This caused a bit more errors, as it was before. Like these: `[Vue warn]: v-bind:class="{"active":showModal}": attribute interpolation is not allowed in Vue.js directives and special attributes. [Vue warn]: Invalid expression. Generated function body: "active":scope.showModal [Vue warn]: Error when evaluating expression ""active":showModal". Turn on debug mode to see stack trace.`

Comment: Thanks a year+ later - drove me crazy what was wrong and turned out I had double " within double "

Comment: It also throws this error: [Vue warn]: Do not mount Vue to <html> or <body> - mount to normal elements instead.